# Find the value of $x$ from $\sin^{4}(x) + \cos^{4}(x) = \sin(x)\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I used the formula $\sin^{4}(x) + \cos^{4}(x) = 1- 2\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}( x)$  and then made $2- \sin^{2}(2x) = \sin(2x)$ by multiplying $2$ on both sides and using $\sin(2x)$ formula but I got stuck here.

Comment: It's still unclear what the final step you got was. Can you please show us a list of steps? You may also find [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) useful.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$? There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $2- \sin^{2}(2x) = \sin(2x) \implies (\sin(2x) + 2)  \ (\sin(2x)-1) = 0$ so $\sin (2x) = 1$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $y = \sin 2x$. Your equation becomes $2 - y^2 = y$ which can be rearranged into $y^2 + y - 2 = 0$. To solve this quadratic equation, factorise by inspection or apply the quadratic formula. Here, you can easily factorise this as $(y-1)(y+2) = 0$, which has the solutions $y = 1$ or $y =-2$. But recall that $y = \sin 2x$, which has absolute value at most $1$, so $y = - 2$ is inadmissible. This leaves $\sin 2x = 1$. Can you solve this for $x$?